# $[0,1]=\bigcap_n \big[0, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big)=\bigcap_n \big [0, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big]$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $[0,1]=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \big [0, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big).$  But it appears to me that it also equals $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \big [0, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big],$ doesn't it?

Let $A\triangleq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \big [0, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big]$.  Clearly $[0,1]\subset A,$ since $[0,1]$ is contained in every $[0, 1+\frac{1}{n}]$.  But for any $x>1$, we can always find an '$n$' so that $x \notin [0, 1+\frac{1}{n}].$ Hence $A=[0,1].$  Am I mistaken ?

More generally, for any real $x < y$ , suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a non-increasing sequence with $a_n > y$ and $a_n \to y$.  Then

$$[x,y]=\bigcap_n[x, a_n]=\bigcap_n[x, a_n)?$$

Similarly, suppose $\{b_n\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence with $b_n < y$ and $b_n \to y$.  Then

$$[x,y)=\bigcup_n[x, b_n]=\bigcup_n[x, b_n)?$$

$\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ may be any real sequence, including a sequence of rationals in particular, right?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, you don't even need your sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ to be non increasing and non decreasing. Any seuence with the convergence property will serve the purpose.

Comment: @Parish Well, we should have $a_n>y>b_n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. Here is some facts that my help you in the future: arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed, and arbitrary union of open sets is open. Therefore
$$ \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+}[x,a_n]$$
should be closed, and equals $[x,y]$ if $a_n > y$ for all $n$ and $a_n \to y.$ Similarly
$$ \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+}[x,b_n)=[x,y)$$
if $x<y,$ $b_n <y$ and $b_n \to y.$ (The above is only half-open, but the argument works and show that the union should be half-open as well.)

As you note, arbitrary intersections of open sets need not be open, and arbitrary unions of closed sets need not be closed.